# Wagtail search doesn't work inside i18n_patterns

Tags: python, django, internationalization, wagtail

I've added a `wagtail-modeltranslation` to my site. Everything works as it should despite the search.
When the search is inside the the regular urlpatterns - it redirects only on `LANGUAGE_CODE` version of the site, but when i put it in the `i18n_patterns` - search stops working and raises 404 error. Why is it so and how to fix it?

Comment: Please give more context https://stackoverflow.com/conduct https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please provide example configuration/source

Answer (score 0):

The language switcher sample code of Wagtail trans (not modeltrans) is made to use with Wagtail page types.

The variable `page` is undefined because search view is not a Wagtail Page but a regular Django view.

Therefore the switcher href isn't set correctly.

[Fix your switcher code to not depend on page. Or start using a Search page type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193166/wagtail-modeltranslation-language-switcher-doesnt-work-on-search-page)

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/advanced_topics/i18n/index.html#serving-different-languages-from-different-urls

#### mysite/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, re_path

[...]

urlpatterns = [...]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(

```
#These URLs will have /<language_code>/ appended to the beginning

re_path(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

re_path(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
```

)

Comment: Please do not answer with link only and documentation example from the link. Instead add an explanation of the problem & solution.