# Wagtail modeltranslation language switcher doesn't work on /search page

Tags: python, django, search, internationalization, wagtail

I have added `search` url to `i18n_patterns`, but the language switcher doesn't work on that page.
*urls.py:*

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("search/", search_views.search, name="search"),
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
)
```

*language switcher:*

```
{% get_available_languages_wmt as languages %}
<div class="nav-item dropdown float-right">
    <p class="nav-link dropdown-toggle m-auto" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        {{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE|upper }}</p>
    <div class="dropdown-menu w-25">
        {% for language in languages %}
        {% if language != request.LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% change_lang language page %}">{{ language|upper }}</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Furthermore, when i add `search` url above `root` one the search page raises 404 page.
How can i make the language switcher work on the search page?

Answer (score 0):

The language switcher uses the Wagtail `page` variable. See the `change_lang` template tag:

```
<a ... href="{% change_lang language page %}">...</a>
```

And search is a Django view, not a Wagtail page. The `page` variable is not defined.

You can make the switcher work on the search view by setting the href yourself:

```
{% for language in languages %}
    <a href="/{{ language.code }}/search/"
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, you can create a Wagtail search page:

```
class SearchPage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)            

        ... # Copy the code from the current search view.

        # Update and return the context
        context.update({
            'search_query': search_query,
            'search_results': search_results,
        })
        return context
```

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context

You also have to:

- Rename (search_page.html) and rework (page.variable_name) your search template.
- Remove the search url from urls.py
- Add the SearchPage via the Wagtail admin interface to the page tree.

Comment: An option with 
```{% for language in languages %}
    <a href="/{{ language.code }}/search/"
{% endfor %}```
doesn't work, because the url has ```?query=...``` part as it is a get request

Comment: It doesn't switch? Or it doesn't preserve your search query? Then add `?query=...` to your href.

Comment: i found out ho to make it work. It's a bad way but it works at least:
```<a class="dropdown-item" href="/{{ language.code }}{{ request.get_full_path }}">{{ language.code|upper }}</a>```